# Interleaving and searching through Logfiles

Tags: python, bash, sorting, search, logging

I have multiple GB of logfiles which I want to search through. Every log has a timestamp, message and additional multiple fields, so each log consists of multiple lines looking like this:

```
Mon Jan 20 12:00:00 2016 127.0.0.1:12345 Hello World!
Field_1 = foo
Field_2 = bar
... (some more fields)
<empty line>
```

Note that this way two logs are separated by a single empty line. Unfortunately only single logfiles are ordered by time, two different logfiles must be interleaved to get the whole ordered line of logs. This is the first thing I want to achieve.

Further I want to search on logs. This basically means that I want to define search terms and grep on each single log. All search terms need to match. So in the end I want have an ordered set of logs which meet my search terms.

I tried to get through this by using the context search of grep but the missing order by time and the fixed context size made it a pain. So I want to ask if there is some Bash or Python magic to let this happen. Every hint is highly appreciated!

Comment: If you know your time format you can use awk https://coderwall.com/p/ueazhw/parsing-logs-with-awk

Comment: @dmitryro Thank you for the link. In fact I was not aware of awk! Together with [this](http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/article/webperf/baslog/statwithbashandawk) I will try to get something running.

Comment: 64 results searching for `[python] parsing logfiles` and 700+ for `[python] logfile`. Did you look at any of them? Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely recommend that you would look at [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
, they have all the things you need! You could make a script that compiles the regex template and then use `re.findall(regex_template, your_log_variable)` < Just an example, you have to fill in your own logs and templates.

Hope this helps you...